# jquery: keydown, keyup, small snippet, why isn't this working?

Tags: jquery, events, keydown, onkeyup, ctrl

Why isn't this working?

```
var holdingctrl = false;
$(document).keydown("q",function(e) {
 if(holdingctrl == true) 
 alert("Holding CTRL and pressing Q: Success.");
 e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).keyup("q",function(e) {
 holdingctrl == false 
});
```

This example below works just fine, but what am i doing wrong above?

```
$(document).keyup("q",function(e) {
 alert("ONLY pressing Q: Success.");
});
```

Comment: You might want to have a look herE: http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2009/06/16/ctrl-key-combination-simple-jquery-plugin/

Comment: When working with key events use console.log for debugging information or you lose the state-ness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed a  way to determine if control was currently being pressed (e.ctrlKey) - This should work for you:

```
  $(document).keyup(function(e) 
    { 
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 81) 
        {
            alert("CTRL+Q Pressed");
        }
    });
```

[Working Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/uDVLY/3/)

Comment: actually, it's also firing when I hold CTRL and press A.... hmm... strange.... and i just realized that pressing a few other keys while holding down ctrl also causes it to fire.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with this snippet, but you can check whether <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is pressed by using the `event.ctrlKey` property:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode == 81)) { // ctrl + q
        alert("Pressing Q and ctrl: Success.");
    }
});
```

Comment: for some reason, this causes the alert to be fired when just pressing ctrl, not even having to press Q. I think it's the 'keydown'? because changing it to keyup fixes the problem.

Comment: @android I've changed the answer to use `e.keycode`, which checks whether the key pressed is `q`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Couple notes:

- the *event data* you're passing should be an object instead of a single character.
- the `keyup` handler isn't doing anything with the `==` comparison. You probably meant to use an `=` assignment.

---

```
$(document).keyup( { theChar:"q" }, function(e) {
   holdingctrl = false;
});
```

Comment: i applied the { theChar:"q" } part of your code to the answer right above yours and it's firing when i press CTRL+Q, but also when I press CTRL+A and CTRL+ a lot of other keys, like P, etc.